# Can a sqlite3 user defined Python function return a string usable as multiple values for an insert statement?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have an expensive function (literally, using a paid web service) that returns multiple values (string, real) that I want to use in an SQLite insert trigger.  I only want to call the function once per row insert.

I can retrieve all values as string using repr on a tuple, say: "('123 Main St, Podunk, NY','Some County',123.456,789.1011)"

When the trigger fires the returned string is interpreted as a single value, not the columns within parentheses, no doubt due to the exterior quoting.

It is easy enough to plug in a single returned value like the sample below but multiple values escape me, has anyone implemented a pattern like that?

```
    import hashlib
    import sqlite3

    def hashaddress(address):
        return hashlib.md5(address.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()

    customers = [('WYLE E COYOTE','702 Acme Rd, Otis, MA, 01253, USA'),
                 ('SYLVESTER T KATT','79 Felix Ave, Methuen, MA, 01844, USA')]

    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    conn.create_function('hashaddress',1,hashaddress)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Customers
               (Name TEXT, Address TEXT, Address_Hash TEXT);''')
    cur.execute('''CREATE TRIGGER HashT AFTER INSERT ON Customers
                BEGIN
                UPDATE Customers SET Address_Hash = hashaddress(NEW.Address)
                WHERE Name = NEW.Name and Address = NEW.Address;
                END;
                ''')
    cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO Customers (Name, Address) VALUES (?,?);
                    ''',customers)
    conn.commit()
    for c in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Customers'):
        print(c)
    for c in cur.execute('SELECT hashaddress(?)',('123 Main St Podunk',)):
        print(c)
    conn.close()
```

Picture the function more like this:

```
    def hashparts(address):
        h = hashlib.md5(address.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        t = (h[:16],h[16:])
        return repr(t)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, but you can split your string, using `,` as a separator in your case: `result_string.split(",")`. You can also format string to do dynamic insert statements. Look at `.format()` in Python doc. (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting)

Comment: Thank you, my apologies my question isn't clear enough, but the values I'm dealing with have embedded commas and Python string functions can only go in the called function as the trigger definition can only use SQL and SQLite functions.

Comment: I think I'll answer my own question here; since I can't figure out how to handle multivalue function responses in SQL I'll push the table handling I need down into the function itself, which makes it a bit opaque and overloaded but works.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed the table handling I wanted to do down into the Python function.